# How to call a function and get updated location in terminated application after some interval in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to call a function and get a user's updated location after some time interval in iOS with swift.
I want to perform operation on the basis of user's updated location even if application not running in background,
Is there any way to awake application in background and perform operation?

Comment: See [Handling Location Events in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background/). My guess is that “significant change” service will be well suited for your needs, but there are links for all the options there.

Comment: BTW, this question has been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow. I’d encourage you to search and research before posting a question. (And if you did research and still had questions, tell us what research you did and tell us what you found unclear.)

Comment: FYI, it’s driven not by “time interval” but rather “has the device changed location significantly.” You do not want to (nor can you) have the app awaken at some consistent interval. Have the device inform you of changes in location and don't drain the battery if the user is not moving.